# Access spring application context from everywhere

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

Let's assume, that I have an `app-context.xml` which loads my beans and stuff like that. Now if I want to use a bean, I need to make these steps:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
MailService ms = (MailService) context.getBean("mailService");
// use MailService
```

How can I skip these steps, since I don't want to load the context, instantiate it, cast the bean to my service every time I send a mail.

Another question. Why does loading XML bean definitions take that much time?
I have 2 beans in the XML, and it takes like 2-3-4 minutes to load. PC is fine, in other applications it loads in seconds.

Comment: What kind of application it is, is it spring boot or maven based project. How many context you maintain in your app? There are several questions to be asked before answering your question. Why not use Autowiring feature of spring framework ?

Comment: Spring boot app, I have only 1 context for testing purposes. I can't autowire it (though I'd very happy if I could do so), because it says 'Could not autowire, no beans of type MailService found'.

Comment: you can use @ImportResource to load the required beans to bootup container for testing resources and use `@Autowiring`

Comment: Do I use @ImportResource on my 'main' class? And then I can use @ Autowire in my e.g RestController?

Comment: yup you can do that I hope main class refers to tthe class annotated with `@SprinBootApplication`.

Comment: Oh man, that works! (Yea, @SpringBootApplication) I'm so happy now, no spaghetti code needed. (Make an answer from your comment and I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@ImportResource` to load the beans from the configuration files.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html